# How to solve this paging error in asp.net mvc 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an asp.net MVC 5 view. I have the following  code on it:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<parishV3.Models.HeadsViewModel>
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;
<link href="~/Content/css/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" />

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Heads", FormMethod.Get))
{
  <p>
    <b> Find by name:</b>@Html.RadioButton("findBy", "fname") <text>First Name</text>
    @Html.RadioButton("findBy", "lname")<text>Last Name</text><br />
    @Html.RadioButton("findBy", "h_no")<text>Header Number</text><br />
    @Html.TextBox("Seach_Data", ViewBag.FilterValue as string, ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
    <input type="submit" value="Find" />
</p>
}

<br />
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, findby =  Request.QueryString["findby"], Seach_Data = Request.QueryString["Seach_Data"] }))
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index(string Seach_Data, string findby, int? page, string currentFilter )
{
    if (findby == "fname")
    {
       string query = "SELECT v.h_no as h_no, v.h_initials , v.h_id as h_id , t.titles as titles,     p.Suburb as Suburb, p.flatNo as flatNo, p.flatName as flatName,v.Email as Email, v.cell as cell,    v.tel_h as tel_h, v.fname as fname, p.strname as strname, p.strNo as strNo, p.City as City, LEFT(v.lname, 255) as lname from [dbo].[Heads] v, [dbo].[Addresses1] p, [dbo].[Titles] t WHERE v.[h_ID] = p.[h_id] and v.[title_id]= t.[title_id] ";

       var ViewModel = db.Database.SqlQuery<HeadsViewModel>(query);
       return View(ViewModel.Where(x => x.fname == Seach_Data).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 4));
    }
    else if (findby == "lname")
    {
        string query = "SELECT v.h_no as h_no, v.h_initials , v.h_id as h_id , t.titles as titles, p.Suburb as Suburb, p.flatNo as flatNo, p.flatName as flatName,v.Email as Email, v.cell as cell,  v.tel_h as tel_h,  v.fname as fname, p.strname as strname, p.strNo as strNo, p.City as City, LEFT(v.lname, 255) as lname from [dbo].[Heads] v, [dbo].[Addresses1] p, [dbo].[Titles] t WHERE v.[h_ID] = p.[h_id] and v.[title_id]= t.[title_id] "; 
        var ViewModel = db.Database.SqlQuery<HeadsViewModel>(query);

        return View(ViewModel.Where(x => x.lname == Seach_Data).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 6));  
    }
    else
    {
      string query = "SELECT v.h_no as h_no, v.h_initials , v.h_id as h_id , t.titles as titles, p.Suburb as Suburb, p.flatNo as flatNo, p.flatName as flatName,v.Email as Email, v.cell as cell,  v.tel_h as tel_h,  v.fname as fname, p.strname as strname, p.strNo as strNo, p.City as City, LEFT(v.lname, 255) as lname from [dbo].[Heads] v, [dbo].[Addresses1] p, [dbo].[Titles] t WHERE v.[h_ID] = p.[h_id] and v.[title_id]= t.[title_id] ";
      var ViewModel = db.Database.SqlQuery<HeadsViewModel>(query);
      return View(ViewModel);
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I run the project it gives me an error that says:

> System.InvalidOperationException:The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbRawSqlQuery`1[parishV3.Models.HeadsViewModel], but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'PagedList.IPagedList`1[parishV3.Models.HeadsViewModel]'."

Comment: Check the type of model you are returning that matches the model defined in the view.

Comment: show all code of Index action please, likely you return incorrect model

Comment: Embedded sql in a controller is wrong on many levels and is worst practice.

Comment: The message tells you everything you need to know - your not passing typeof `PagedList.IPagedList<parishV3.Models.HeadsViewModel>` to the model so change your action method to return it!

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you assist me with the code that i should use on the action method

Comment: @Venkat dont think i get u clearly

Comment: @asawyer can u please assist me with correct one please.

Comment: The problem is in the initial page load when `findby` is null, so it executes the final `else` block which returns `ViewModel` not a `ToPagedList` as you have used in the other `if` blocks.

Comment: @StephenMuecke so what should i add or remove?

Comment: Instead of `return View(ViewModel);` you need something like `return View(ViewModel.ToList().ToPagedList(1, 6));` but you have other issues also, not the least being you have not ordered you query so you could end up with unpredictable results anyway

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you its working, but on thing that is not working is Search.

Comment: @Everyone commented here thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the initial page load the value of the `findby` is null so the `else` block is executed which returns `DbRawSqlQuery1<parishV3.Models.HeadsViewModel>` but your view requires the model to be `IPagedList1<parishV3.Models.HeadsViewModel>`. Change you `else` block to

```
else
{
  string query = ".....";
  var ViewModel = db.Database.SqlQuery<HeadsViewModel>(query);
  return View(ViewModel.ToList().ToPagedList(1, 6));
}
```

Note when using a paged list, you query should include an `OrderBy` clause to ensure the collection is always returned in the same order otherwise you may get unpredictable results.

Comment: if you want paging changes to another number you must do this"ToPagedList( page ?? 1, 6)"

Comment: Sure, but I assumed the `else` block is for the initial page load only, in which case you want the first page which is why I just did `ToPagedList(1, 6)`, but if `findby` could be null in other cases, best to use `( page ?? 1, 6)`.